# GitLab CE: Block new users after manual registration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

I am locking for the right GitLab CE server configuration to block new users, which signed up manually via the sign-up page (username / name / password). This users should be blocked until manually confirmed by an admin.

I found options to block new (auto-created) users for `LDAP` and `OmniAuth` in [`gitlab.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example) but not for plain user accounts, who just registered on the sign-up page:

```
## LDAP settings
  ldap:
    servers:
      main:
        block_auto_created_users: true

## OmniAuth settings
omniauth:
  block_auto_created_users: true
```

I want to let the users register themselves, so completely disabling this the admin area is not wanted:

---

[image: admin area sign-in restrictions]

---

How can I configure GitLab CE to block new users who just signed-up so that I have an admin confirmation for new users (not using `LDAP` or `OmniAuth`)?

GitLab version is `8.5.7 CE`.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent new users from doing. If you just want to prevent them from creating new projects, then you can set the default project to 0, and then increase it when you "approve" them.

Comment: Yeah, this is the current setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now (October 2020) have an alternative with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#required-approval-for-new-user-registration):

> ### Required approval for new user registration
>
> To reduce the operational burden on GitLab administrators without compromising security, GitLab 13.5 introduces a new instance-level option to require administrator approval for any new user accounts.
>
> This option is disabled by default but when enabled, will require manual approval by instance administrators before users that completed the sign-up process can access the instance.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#require-admin-approval-for-new-sign-ups) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4491).

And:

See [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#admin-approval-required-by-default-for-new-user-registrations) (November 2020)

> ### Admin approval required by default for new user registrations
>
> In GitLab 13.5, we introduced the option to [require administrator approval for new user registrations](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#required-approval-for-new-user-registration).
>
> To increase security of our default configuration, GitLab 13.6 makes this option the default experience for new instances.
>
> We have also introduced email notifications to instance administrators when a new signup occurs and to users when their registration is approved.
> Email notifications at these critical steps in the process help reduce the turnaround time to onboard users when administrator approval is required.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#require-administrator-approval-for-new-sign-ups) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4491).

Comment: Great news! It is also in the [GitLab CE documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#require-admin-approval-for-new-sign-ups)